# How do I use greater than and less than in COUNTIFS as an AND cretiria?

Tags: excel, formula

What I need is something like
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,">=1",A2:A9,"<=3").
I know this works just fine but I wonder if I can make it shorter.

I'm looking for something like
=COUNTIFS(A2:A9,{">=1","<=3"}).
But turns out the { } combines ">=1" and "<=3" with an OR function. What I want is to put the two cretiria within AND. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that's what you mean.It's not shorter

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A2:A9,">"&{0,3})*{1,-1})
```

Comment: Didn't know SUM and COUNTIFS can be used this way. Thanks a lot.